# Why AWS lambda custom php run time throw the error "error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file:..."?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, runtime

I have created custom `php-7.0.6` run time on `EC2 instance` of AWS, which uses Amazon Linux , using the following command :

`./configure --prefix=/home/ec2-user/php-7-bin/ --without-pear --enable-shared=no --enable-static=yes --enable-phar --enable-json --disable-all --with-openssl --with-curl --enable-libxml --enable-simplexml --enable-xml --with-mhash --with-gd --enable-exif --with-freetype-dir --enable-mbstring --enable-sockets --enable-pdo --with-pdo-mysql --enable-tokenizer --with-zlib`

when i use the binary file generated through this command, on a aws lambda configuration the lambda function throws a error with message like :

`php: error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

**Note:** the binary file works fine on EC2 server while checking `phpinfo()` using this binary file.

Please help me out with this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after spending too much time i came to know that it was my mistake.
i haven't used right ec2 instance described by [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/aws-lambda-custom-runtime-for-php-a-practical-example/) documentation.
After following steps properly php binary file get working.
the required configuration for lambda is [AWS Lambda Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html)